# Convert 360 PNG sequence to single mesh?

Tags: mesh

I'm pretty new to Blender, and 3d software generally (traditionally an After Effects and hand-drawn animator), so apologies if this is something you very obviously can't do, but I'm wondering if it's possible to take an existing 360 PNG sequence and (relatively quickly) use the different angles of view to create a single mesh. I know theoretically I could do so by creating a wireframe of each image before joining them up, but this would obviously be ridiculous and insanely time-consuming, so far quicker just to make my own object from scratch.

I'm pretty sure that last part will be the response I get, which is cool. I'm just curious if the community has any thoughts :)

PS - I did see a question similar to this has been asked before, but that was 2017 so perhaps features added to Blender since have changed things somewhat...

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for photogrammetry software. Blender isn't the tool for this, neither now or before, while it can be used for cleaning scanned objects up. Try Meshroom (free) or Metashape (ex-Photoscan)

Comment: If you still have the object, I might use the Qlone app on your phone. If you don’t, you might be able to use motion tracking on the object, and then convert the tracks to mesh, though you could end up with a very low poly object.

Comment: Yeah, I was 99% sure this was the case but being fresh to Blender thought it would checking. I ended up modelling a similar asset from scratch in the end, which while nowhere near the quality of the png object I was hoping to recreate was still useable for my purposes and, more importantly, a valuable practice. But thanks for taking the time to respond both. Bad form on my part for replying so late!